# Clever way of combining two columns in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, group-concat, reformat

I'm sorry if this fells like code golf, but I trying to avoid getting data out of the database, do processing in application code for something that would require slooow loops over a data set where there are indices that would help in the grouping.

Is there any way at all to get from a data set like this:

```
sqlite> create table tst  (id INTEGER, label TEXT, variable TEXT, value FLOAT);
sqlite> insert into tst values (1,"label1","variable 1",1.2);
sqlite> insert into tst values (1,"label2","variable 2",2.2);
sqlite> insert into tst values (1,"label3","variable 3",3.2);
sqlite> select * from tst;
id          label       variable    value     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           label1      variable 1  1.2       
1           label2      variable 2  2.2       
1           label3      variable 3  3.2
```

to be returned like this (with the names of the output columns being constructed from the content of the `variable` and `label` column content):

```
sqlite> <magic query here> 
id          label1_variable1   label2_variable2    label3_variable3     
----------  ----------         ----------          ----------
1           1.2                2.2                 3.2
```

that is, in wide format rather than long format?

Please advice, or help me just by proving that is cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a pivot query:

```
SELECT id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'label1' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS 'label1_variable1',
    SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'label2' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS 'label2_variable2',
    SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'label3' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS 'label3_variable3'
FROM tst
GROUP BY id
```

You cannot perform a pivot query in SQLite with an unknown set of columns because doing so would require dynamic SQL.  As user @CL. mentioned in his comment below, one way to simulate dynamic SQL would be to first do a `SELECT DISTINCT label FROM tst` to obtain the set of all columns, followed by a pivot query resembling what I gave above.  You would have to construct the pivot query programatically from your app layer.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was not clear in my question. I would need the names of the columns to be created to be unknown at the time when the query is formulated. So that, if there is also a "label4" in `label`, and a "variable4" in `variable` then I would also get a `label4_variable4` column in the output.

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL to achieve this and I don't know whether SQLite supports dynamic SQL.

Comment: It doesn't; SQLite is an embedded database designed to be used together with a 'real' programming language.

Comment: @CL. Then can we give the verdict that he cannot achieve what he wants?

Comment: That depends. Does doing a `SELECT DISTINCT label` first to be able to construct the pivot query count as "looping over the data"?

Comment: Maybe I am thick or something, but I think I need more details to be able to understand how `select distinct label` solves the issue? I need a small illustration, please!

Comment: I am also thick, but appreciate that doing a `SELECT DISTINCT label` will give you the set of all columns to be used in the pivot query.  Dynamic SQL will let you iterate over this set to generate the `CASE WHEN` clauses you want in your output.  If this still be unclear then maybe you should ask a new question and reference this one.

Comment: Ok. SQLite has no procedural language, only the functional SQL, so what is required is some application code. Sorry for the late reply, but thanks!